# Translate labels from yml to php file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have a YAML file with a bunch of translations, like this:

```
wizard
  admin
    title: example
```

And I'm calling it on the PHP file like this:

```
public function getTypesChart(){
   $charts = array(
      array(
        'title' => 'wizard.admin.title'
      ),
   );
   return $charts;
}
```

But the only output I get it's "wizard.admin.title" instead of "example".

Comment: It may be useful to look at yaml_parse php function

Comment: Please note that this input file is invalid YAML

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the translator service, like this (assuming you are in a controller, or where you have your service container):

```
public function getTypesChart(){
    $charts = array(
        array(
        'title' => $this->get('translator')->trans('wizard.admin.title')
        ),
    );
    return $charts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you put your translation key in something automatically translated (like form's field label), you need to explicitly ask translation to do the job.

Assuming your code is in some controller you can call:

```
$this->get("translator")->trans("wizard.admin.title");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here. First and foremost is that your input is not valid YAML:

```
wizard
  admin
    title: example
```

Although you can have multiline unquoted scalars in YAML, as in:

```
 x: wizard
      admin
        title
```

(which is the same as doing `x: 'wizard admin title'` or `x: wizard admin title`) such scalars cannot be used as keys for a mapping.

Being invalid, you'll have to correct your YAML to be:

```
wizard:
  admin:
    title: example
```

after correcting that, make sure you call the [translater](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#basic-translation)

```
public function getTypesChart(){
   $charts = array(
      array(
        'title' => $this->get('translator')->trans('wizard.admin.title')
      ),
   );
   return $charts;
}
```